# Loop Logic PHP went wrong

Tags: php, mysql, loops, date, datetime

Okay, let's say i have a following table :

```
CREATE TABLE booking (
    idBooking INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    bookingDate DATE,
    roomId INTEGER,
    startHour TIME,
    endHour TIME
);
```

and the table has 3 record :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/675BA.png)

i worked with framework codeigniter, and here's my view :

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Start Hour</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
    $open_time = "07:00:00";
    $close_time = "15:00:00";

    for( $i=$open_time; $i<$close_time; $i+=3600) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td >
            <?php $timeloop = date('H:i:s', $i); echo $timeloop; ?> </h1>
        </td>

        <td>
            <?php 
                $count = count($bookingList);
                for ($j=0; $j < $count ; $j++) { 
                        $endtime1 = strtotime($timeloop)+3600;
                        $endtime2 =  date('H:i:s', $endtime1);
                    if ($bookingList[$j]->startHour == $timeloop ||$bookingList[$j]->endHour == $endtime2 ) { 
                    ?>  <span>Booked </span> <?php  
                    } 
                    else { ?>  <span> Available</span>
                <?php
                        }
                } ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php }  ?>
</tbody>
```

So, i would like to show available hours based on the booking table, which means there's no record in the table.
Here's my expectation :

> 07:00:00  Available
>   08:00:00    Booked
>   09:00:00    Booked
>   10:00:00    Available
>   11:00:00    Available
>   12:00:00    Booked
>   13:00:00    Available
>   14:00:00    Available
>   15:00:00    Available

But, something's wrong with the loop, i have no idea how to define the logic, it's work really fine when the table only had 1 record, 
but, when i inserted another record, something went wrong, here's what happened

> 07:00:00  Available Available Available
>   08:00:00    Booked Available Available
>   09:00:00    Available Booked Available
>   10:00:00    Available Available Available
>   11:00:00    Available Available Available
>   12:00:00    Available Available Booked
>   13:00:00    Available Available Available
>   14:00:00    Available Available Available
>   15:00:00    Available Available Available

Your prompt response is highly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for days :(

Comment: Are you trying to add `(int) 3600` to `(string) 07:00:00` cause that is not going to work at all...

Comment: That's not how looping works in php. As @prodigitalson mentioned, you can't add an int to a string and expect the loop to work properly. You should read the php docs first before asking questions IMHO.

Comment: did you guys miss my point ? the problem is  not that part, please reread my question fellas

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "for" statement to loop through a database table. Use "while", since you know that the number of records can change.

1) Pass the logic to the SQL query;
2) Execute query with PHP;

Exemple:

```html
/* open th database connection */
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");

/* check if the connection was successful */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* query your database using the logic inside the query*/
$query = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE openHour = '12:00' AND closeHour = '17:00'";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{

?>

<td><?php echo $row['openHour']; ?><td>
<td><?php echo $row['closeHour']; ?><td>
<td>
<?php
    if(date('H:m:i') == $row['openHour'] OR date('H:m:i') == $row['closeHour']){
        echo "Booked";
    }
?>
<td>

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: you have any example ?